# JAXB: Add namespace to second level

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to add the namespace urn:com.workday/bsvc to the second element in the xml i generate.
This is what i want to generate:

[image]

But i don't know how to specify it in my class.
I added this to my class Put_Absence_Input_Request :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [download (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.2.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-workday-2.2.0-mvn-src.zip) contains a stand-alone Maven project to unmarshal the given XML [workday-01.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/test/samples/workday-01.xml) file into JAXB objects and then marshal the objects back into XML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvo">
    <wd:Put_Absence_Input_Request wd:version="v39.2">
        <wd:Absence_Input_Data>
            <wd:Batch_ID>Import 15022023</wd:Batch_ID>
            <wd:Worker_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">1741538</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker_Reference>
            <wd:Absence_Component_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Accrual_Code">FRA_Shadow_Accrual_for_Time_Offs_Impacting_Accrual_of_Paid_Annual_Leave_CP</wd:ID>
            </wd:Absence_Component_Reference>
            <wd:Start_Date>2023-01-01</wd:Start_Date>
            <wd:End_Date>2023-01-31</wd:End_Date>
            <wd:Reference_Date>2023-01-15</wd:Reference_Date>
            <wd:Hours>2.08</wd:Hours>
            <wd:Adjustment>false</wd:Adjustment>
        </wd:Absence_Input_Data>
    </wd:Put_Absence_Input_Request>
</root>
```

The `root` element *does not* declare a namespace for itself but it does declare a namespace for the child elements.

##### Here's How

The configuration of the `"urn:com.workday/bsvo"` namespace is declared in the JAXB context using:

**`com/workday/bsvo/package-info.java`**

```
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
(
    namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvo",
    elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns =
    {
        @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs
        (
            prefix = "wd",
            namespaceURI = "urn:com.workday/bsvo"
        )
    }
)
package com.workday.bsvo;
```

**Additionally**, the namespace prefix is optionally configured to be `wd:` to override the generic `ns1` prefix.

The Maven project generates the Java (JAXB) classes from these XML schemas and a binding file:

- [src/main/resource/root.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xjb)
- [src/main/resource/root.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xsd)
- [src/main/resource/wd.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/wd.xsd)

The [HiSrc HigherJAXB Maven Plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) is used to generate the JAXB classes:

> **Note:** This is a "schema first" design pattern; but, you can use the generated Java classes as a model for a "code first" approach.

```
target
└── generated-sources
    └── xjc
        ├── com
        │   └── workday
        │       ├── bsvo
        │       │   ├── AbsenceComponentReference.java
        │       │   ├── AbsenceInputData.java
        │       │   ├── ID.java
        │       │   ├── ObjectFactory.java
        │       │   ├── package-info.java
        │       │   ├── PutAbsenceInputRequest.java
        │       │   └── WorkerReference.java
        │       ├── ObjectFactory.java
        │       ├── package-info.java
        │       └── Root.java
        ├── JAXBDebug.java
        └── META-INF
            └── sun-jaxb.episode
```

The [root.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xjb) binding file customizes the Java *package path* for the namespace-less `root` classes and a child path for the `workday` classes to keep things orderly. The [wd.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/wd.xsd) declares its own target namespace and the [root.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xsd) intentionally omits a target namespace.

Also, the [root.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xjb) binding file customizes the workday level `package-info.java` to use the more friendly prefix, `wd:`. The [HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox XJC Plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) is used to customize the prefix. This is optional. If this customization is omitted, JAXB will declare the `"urn:com.workday/bsvo"` namespace in `package-info.java`, as desired, but the prefix will be arbitrary (i.e. `ns1`).

Also, the [HiSrc BasicJAXB XJC Plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) is used to generate value specific methods for `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString`. The generation of these methods is optional but it provides a human-readable `toString` output for the sample [Main.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/java/com/workday/bsvo/Main.java) application.

##### Execution

This is a stand-alone Maven project. After [unzipping](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.2.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-workday-2.2.0-mvn-src.zip) it to your local folder, you can run the test using:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
```

Or execute the sample application using:

```
mvn -Pexec clean compile exec:java
```

This [output](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/OUTPUT.txt) shows the test results.

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the HiSrc projects.